# How to use AND in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently having hard time creating a formula for my sheet to record values when the following conditions will be met:
I want to give 15% discount from the original price if a Person purchased their ticket online (`Online = TRUE`), and only applicable for customers who is atleast 50 years old, kindly list the new calculated discounted price in the `Discounted Price` Column

I have tried creating a formula but I got `formula parse error`.
Formula used : `=IF((B2=TRUE AND D2>50),(E2*0.85),E2)`

This is my sample data in the sheet and the expected output on Discounted Price column. Any help will be appreciated.

| Person | Online | Physical Store | Age | Original Price | Discounted Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | TRUE | FALSE | 67 | 1000 | 850 |
| B | TRUE | FALSE | 16 | 1000 | 1000 |
| C | FALSE | TRUE | 24 | 1000 | 1000 |
| D | TRUE | FALSE | 52 | 1000 | 850 |
| E | FALSE | TRUE | 60 | 1000 | 1000 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is almost correct except for the `AND` operator, the syntax for using AND is as follows: `AND(logical_expression1, [logical_expression2, ...])`.

I have replicated your data and fix the formula. Please see formula and desired output below

### Formula:

`=IF(AND(B2=TRUE,D2>50),(E2*0.85),E2)`

### Data and Output:

[image]

### References:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301?hl=en

Comment: I missed that! Thank you very much, all good now on my end

Comment: Great, glad to hear I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="",,IF((B2:B=TRUE)*(D2:D>50), (E2:E*0.85), E2:E))
```